# subprocess.Popen("pytest") returns 2 although pytest returns 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, pytest

I'm running pytest from a `subprocess.Popen`.

As can be seen from the code below and it's output, the pytest exits with exit code 1 but the process thinks it exited with exit code 2. Why? *(currently thinking its a pytest bug [the error matches the description but not the code which makes me think they forgot updating it])*

***[The error itself is not the issue (it stems from having multiple conftest files, and it is ok, as I want to create errors)]***

```
In [1]:     from subprocess import Popen
   ...:     p = Popen('pytest -s -k some_phrase'.split())
   ...:     p.communicate()
   ...:     print p.poll()
   ...: 



Test session starts (platform: linux2, Python 2.7.12, pytest 4.5.0, pytest-sugar 0.9.2)
rootdir: /...
plugins: timeout-1.3.3, sugar-0.9.2, repeat-0.8.0, metadata-1.8.0, html-1.20.0, cov-2.7.1
collecting ... Failed to import pybind11_tests from pytest:
  ImportError: No module named pybind11_tests

―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― test session ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:377: in visit
    for x in Visitor(fil, rec, ignore, bf, sort).gen(self):
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:429: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:429: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:429: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:419: in gen
    if p.check(dir=1) and (rec is None or rec(p))])
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py:660: in _recurse
    ihook = self.gethookproxy(dirpath)
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py:481: in gethookproxy
    my_conftestmodules = pm._getconftestmodules(fspath)
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:421: in _getconftestmodules
    mod = self._importconftest(conftestpath.realpath())
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:443: in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:668: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:301: in load_module
    exec(co, mod.__dict__)
...
    sys.exit(1)
E   SystemExit: 1

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Results (0.44s):
2
```

BTW, I checked the same using `os.system('pytest -s -k bla')`, and there I got error code 512.  It seems the exit code is not propagating properly at all...

---

I tried it again with an new expected error - I now expect no tests collected, and it seems like the error code is right:

```
In [3]:     from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_output
   ...:     p = Popen('pytest --disable-warnings -s -k some_phrase', shell=True)
   ...:     p.communicate()
   ...:     print p.poll()
   ...: 
...

Results (2.59s):
    4275 deselected
5
```

And this is the right code, per [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html)

Possible exit codes
Running pytest can result in six different exit codes:

```
Exit code 0:    All tests were collected and passed successfully
Exit code 1:    Tests were collected and run but some of the tests failed
Exit code 2:    Test execution was interrupted by the user
Exit code 3:    Internal error happened while executing tests
Exit code 4:    pytest command line usage error
Exit code 5:    No tests were collected   <----
```

Comment: Try `p.join()` instead of `poll`. Poll only checks whether the process finished, but `.join` actually waits for it to terminate.

Comment: `communicate` blocks until it is done, so no need for `join` (this is somewhat hacky, but it is ok for a demo)

Comment: It's unclear to me what the incorrect error code is in your first example. `2` is returned by pytest when the execution is interrupted, which appears to be the case. It looks like pytest was still running after it encountered the ImportError (which resulted in an error code of 1, from `sys.exit(1)`, but that is not a return code), and the interrupt caused an exit code of `2` to be returned.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's more like an incomplete documentation - `pytest` exits with code 2 on test collection errors as it is also an early interruption of test execution. The docs aren't just clear enough about that.